# Ubuntu 20.04: Can't boot, ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

my Ubuntu fails to boot. It gives this error for a few seconds and goes black screen.

```
0.218897) ACPI BIOS Error (bug) : Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIOI, AE_N
OT_FOUND (20210730/dsuload2-162)
[
0.213409] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps object-220)
0.599471] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size o is invalid
0.602142] pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
0.790426] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 /dev/nvmeOn1p5: clean, 1473788/13107200 files, 48614212/52428800 blocks
```

I assume it is because of nvidia drivers. I might have messed up some things on the way while working on GPU or upgrading some packages. When I try recover mode --> normal mode I can boot it. Is there a way to fix this? My ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: Turn of secure boot in uefi and try again